# Success function never get invoked in jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i can records to database using jquery and webmethod But Success method could never get invoked... Alert message never shown...

```
    function d(t) {
                  e.ajax({
                  url: "productmodel.aspx/AddProductToCart",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: JSON.stringify(t),
                  dataType: "json",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  sucess: function () {
                  alert("added to cart successfully");
                }
             })
           }



           [WebMethod]
           public static void AddProductToCart(int productid)
            {
               MyShoppingCart usersShoppingCart = new MyShoppingCart();
               String cartId = usersShoppingCart.GetShoppingCartId();
                try
                {
                 usersShoppingCart.AddItem(cartId, productid, 1);
                }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                  throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                  }
              }
```

Comment: The obvious next step here if `success` is not getting called is to supply a handler for `error` and see what error is being reported.  First step of debugging, see what errors are being reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can record the data to DB just not getting the response, you can modify the void method to return HttpResponseMessage back to page with customized error handling message. As for the Ajax call, try this:

```
  function d(t) {
                   var isSuccess = false;
                          e.ajax({
                          url: "productmodel.aspx/AddProductToCart",
                          type: "POST",
                          data: JSON.stringify(t),
                          dataType: "json",
                          async:false,
                          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                          success: function () {
                            isSuccess = true;
                          },
                          error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            isSuccess = false;
                          }

                     });
                     alert(isSuccess);
                     return isSuccess;
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$.ajax({
url: "productmodel.aspx/AddProductToCart",
              type: "POST",
              data: {productid : 1 },
              dataType: "json",
              sucess: function () {
              alert("added to cart successfully");
            }
});
```

Structure of `t` in your code should look like `{ productid : 1 }`

Answer (score 0):

success needs to have two "c"s. that should fix your issue.